# Centos postgres connect

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos6, postgresql-9.3

When you try to connect to postgres:

```
# psql -h localhost dgrt postgres
I get an error:
#User "postgres" has not passed authentication (Ident)
```

Configuration  my files
postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
#Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
#replication privilege.

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

Comment: #UPDATE:
Version:
Centos 6
Postgresql 9.3

Comment: you probably run it as not postgres. when you use `ident` for localhost, `peer` used - it means your os user should match postgres, so to login as postgres to db you have to be postgres on os

Comment: #UPDATE 2:
I need to connect not to the local server but to the remote server
#psql -h 10.10.10.2 dgrt postgres

Comment: in this cace `psql -h localhost` and quoted lines from hba_conf are irrelevant?..

Comment: lines frim hba_conf:
host all all ::1/32 ident

Comment: this line is for local connections as well

Comment: Much to learn, you still have...

Comment: @VaoTsun `::1/128` is localhost -- `::1/32` is just wrong.

Comment: wrong mask for v6 doesn't make it not localhost, or maybe does... anyway it is not the line for remote connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ident` auth you need to launch the command as the correct OS user, i.e., the database username must match the OS username on the local host.

For example (as root) you can do:

```
# su postgres -c 'psql dgrt'
```

The same applies to connections to remote hosts. For details, please refer to the documentation.

For reference:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html